# Counting the number of '#define's in a file

Tags: qt, loops, line, c-preprocessor

Well, I've asked before how to check for each `#include` in a file. Could someone give me an example to check how many `#define`s are from the start of the file to the end?

I've been trying but without success.

Comment: Do you want to check for the number of #defines in the same process, or do you wish to read the source code from a different process - This should not be difficult task.. ?

Comment: I meant: For example i have a .pro file (Project file) that file has #define's & #include's. I want to read that file and check how many #include's and #define's there are.

Comment: You might want to post the .pro file excerpt so that your problem is better understood.  Otherwise it's a simple string match in Perl for example on `/^\s*#/ && (/\s*define/ || /\s*include)` where `\s*` is 0 or more whitespace.  The expression may not be exact but you get the idea.

Comment: The pro file is just a project file which will contain just the #includes and #defines. Eg:

#define Test1
#define Test2
#include "Test1.cod"
#include "Test2.cod"

Comment: @Kazuma: if you have the code to check for `#include`s, adapting that to check for `#define`s should be trivial. Please post the code you have and what you tried to do this yourself.

Comment: @Mat: I don't have any code. I don't know how to count how many #include's and #define's there are.

Comment: @Kazuma: what does the first sentence in your question mean then? And what have you tried? Reading a file an looking for strings in it is covered by the Qt docs pretty well.

Comment: And what about if i want to return the line. I meant If the current line is #include or #define i want to return the full line. For example: #include "Lol.cod" or #define TEST

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/UNIX:

```
egrep -c "\#include|\#define" <filename>
```

This will give you a count of occurrences of both patterns in the file.  If you want it separated:

```
grep -c \#include <filename>
```

gives count of `#include`s

```
grep -c \#define <filename>
```

gives count of `#define`s

```
grep \#include <filename>
```

gives all lines for `#include`s

```
grep \#define <filename>
```

gives all lines for `#defines`s

If you want to be fancy and sophisticated in Perl:

```
$include_count = 0;
$define_count = 0;
open SOURCE, $filename || die $!;
while(<SOURCE>)
{
     next if( !~ /include/ && !~ /define/ );
     $line = $_;
     $orig_line = $line;
     $line =~ s/^\s+//g;
     next if( $line !~ /^# );
     if( $line =~ /include/ ) 
     {
         $include_count++;
         print "$orig_line";
     }
     if( $line =~ /define/ )
     {
         $define_count++;
         print "$orig_line";
     }
}
print "Define count $define_count . Include Count: $include_count\n";
```

This is a quick and dirty script so you can base your solution on this one or write it in Python/C/C++ or any other language you see fit.